# Simplepie not displaying RSS Feed

Tags: php, simplepie

I am using `simplepie-1.5` but it's not displaying any RSS feed. I am only getting white page.

Code:

```
<?php
require_once 'autoloader.php';
$url = 'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml';
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($url);
$feed->init();
?>
<?php
    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
?>
<li> 
    <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Try using var_dump, var_export or print_r to echo your response.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows like this `var_dump($item->get_title());`?

Comment: var_dump($feed); and then show us the result

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows Just did it, I got lengthy result. I placed `var_dump($feed);` after `init();`